# msbuild.exe is not recognized command after build in Jenkins

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, jenkins

**1. sharing violation**

after following http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/convert-vs-2010-database-project-to-ssdt-and-automate-publishing-with-jenkins-part-33/

```
    echo 'Copying Adventure Works Solution to Jenkins workspace...'
xcopy /s /E /H /Y /R "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace" 

echo 'Deleting artifacts from previous builds...'
del "%WORKSPACE%\*_publish.zip" /F /Q
```

**2.Build ms project with MS build**

After add C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ environment variables path
and set build C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe in Jenkins

```
'C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sqlproj' /p:Configuration=Database3 /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:Build;Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath='C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.publish.xml' /p:UpdateDatabase=False


Executing the command cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sqlproj" /p:Configuration=Database3 /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:Build;Publish "/p:SqlPublishProfilePath=C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDatabase=False C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sqlproj" /p:Configuration=Database3 /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:Build;Publish "/p:SqlPublishProfilePath=C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDatabase=False C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
'msbuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,


C:\Users\User2>cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual S
tudio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sqlproj" /p:Configuration=Database3 /p:P
latform=AnyCPU /t:Build;Publish "/p:SqlPublishProfilePath=C:\Users\LAB-User2\Doc
uments\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDat
abase=False C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe && exit %%
ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18034]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

**update**
Full Console output

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1045566609826009314.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace>echo 'Copying Adventure Works Solution to Jenkins workspace...' 
'Copying Adventure Works Solution to Jenkins workspace...'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace>xcopy /s /E /H /Y /R "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace"  
C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sln
C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.v11.suo
C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\excludefiles.txt
C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3\Database3.dbmdl
Sharing violation

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace>echo 'Deleting artifacts from previous builds...' 
'Deleting artifacts from previous builds...'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace>del "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace\*_publish.zip" /F /Q 
Could Not Find C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace\*_publish.zip

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace>exit 0 
Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sqlproj" /p:Configuration=Database3 /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:Build;Publish "/p:SqlPublishProfilePath=C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDatabase=False C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\testing003\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe "C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.sqlproj" /p:Configuration=Database3 /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:Build;Publish "/p:SqlPublishProfilePath=C:\Users\LAB-User2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Database3\Database3.publish.xml" /p:UpdateDatabase=False C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
'msbuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to build a .NET project using Jenkins, follow these steps:

1. Install [MsBuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin)
2. Go to `Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System`
   (On newer versions: `Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration ->  MSBuild`)
   [image: msbuild]
3. In the MSBuild section click the **AddMsBuild** button and specify the details:

   - Name: Name of the MsBuild
   - Path to MsBuild: Specify the path of msbuild.exe. Example: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe`
4. Save and apply the changes.
5. Select your job.
6. Select **Add Build Step**.
7. Select MsBuild version.
8. Specify the path to the project file (.csproj or .sln)

[image: msbuild in project]

9. Build your project.

Comment: do you mean that you can't see this Jenkins->Manage Jenkins ->Configure System option?

Comment: i see this option and apply this MSbuild already, however still not recognized command

Comment: you have to specify your msbuild.exe path in jenkins configure system option and not in your jobs configure option

Comment: and in your job's configure settings select the name of your msbuild ( in my case it is ( Net3.5)  ,and in MsBuild file specify the path to your project, exaple E:\test\abc.csproj

Comment: I had the same issue, the path to MSBUild needs to have the path of MSBuild.exe, which should not include msbuild.exe

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 2.1.7 installed as a Windows service via the Windows Installer.  I do not see anything in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System having to do with MSBuild.  I've installed the MSBuild plugin, but don't see it in configure Jenkins.  Is this a bug in 2.1.7?

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue as @Matt it appears this setting has moved in recent versions of Jenkins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938757/msbuild-plugin-configuration-in-not-available-in-jenkins-configuration-page

Comment: It has been moved from Configure System to Global Tool Configuration

Answer (score 7):

For the newer version of Jenkins, this option is available under this section ..

```
Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration ->  MSBuild
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37939483/2880781

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of jenkins (3.0), you have to configure MSBuild in in the `Tools>Manage Jenkins` menu. Name a job here eg: `msbuild`.
Once that is done, go to the job. Under the MSBuild module select the build (in this case `msbuild`) and now kick off the job. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

select the MSBuild Version in job's configuration,and the MSBuild Version is configured in your jenkins' configure system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Visual Studio on the Server
2. Log into your Jenkins
3. Install the MSBuild Plugin
4. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration
5. Click MSBuild Installations
6. Click Add MSBuild
7. Name:  Visual Studio   (i.e. Visual Studio 2019 Community)
8. Path to MSBuild (i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin)
   [image]
9. Click Save
10. Go to your Jenkins Project
11. Click Configure
12. Go to Build
13. Select your MSBuild Version
14. Enter the name of your Solutin File
    [image]